# Pydantic models not hidden in FastAPI OpenAPI documentation

Tags: python, fastapi, openapi, pydantic

I'm working on a FastAPI application where I'm trying to hide certain Pydantic models from appearing in the OpenAPI documentation generated by FastAPI. I've followed the documentation and set the **`"include_in_schema"`** attribute to **`False`** within the **`Config`** class of the Pydantic models I want to hide. However, despite these settings, the models still appear in the generated documentation.

Here's an example of one of the Pydantic models I'm trying to hide:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class CardBalanceRequest(BaseModel):
    card_no: str = Field(..., example="1234567890123456")
    client_id: str = Field(..., example="1234")

    class Config:
        json_schema_extra = {
            "include_in_schema": False,
        }
```

And here's how I'm initializing my FastAPI app in the main file:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from routers.card_balance import CardBalanceRouter

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(CardBalanceRouter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8888, reload=True)
```

Comment: The inner `Config` class was removed in Pydantic v2: which version of Pydantic and FastAPI are you using? Are you using the models in any endpoints?

Comment: Here are my versions:
FastAPI - 0.110.0
Pydantic - 2.6.4

Yes, I have defined several Pydantic models.